# Uso das Reticências na Transcrição

Tags: ortografia, português-europeu, pontuação

Ao obter o resultado de um exame, constatei que nas zonas de transcrição de um excerto do texto (nas minhas respostas) me foi retirado um ponto por cada vez que recorria às reticências: ...
Sei que, quando se sente a necessidade de remover uma secção do texto que não é relevante, se utilizam reticências situadas entre parênteses retos, como a seguir demonstrado:

- "O homem da aldeia [...] sentia-se solitário", removendo o modificador presente originalmente ("O homem da aldeia, triste e contemplativo, sentia-se solitário").

Contudo, foi-me ensinado que, quando se tenciona transcrever uma longa porção de texto, mas cujo conteúdo não pretendemos remover, reticências sem parênteses retos devem ser utilizadas:

- "Onde há paisagens ... o mundo pode ser" - encurtando a versão original ("Onde há paisagens que não pode haver./Tão belas que são como que o veludo/Do tecido que o mundo pode ser.").

Foi com esta mentalidade que eu elaborei o meu exame, contudo, a correção parece-me revelar que perdi vários pontos, um por cada vez que inseri reticências SEM os parênteses retos.

Estará a minha suposição correta? E, se sim, será legítimo eu pedir uma reavaliação do meu exame?

Comment: Que exame era este?

Comment: O exame nacional de Português do 12.º Ano. Uma prova de relevância acentuada, na minha opinião.

Comment: Comentário de brasileira (não sou portuguesa): a forma correta de anotar uma omissão dentro de uma transcrição segundo a ABNT é reticências entre *colchetes* (parênteses) [colchetes] {chaves}. As reticências sem parênteses anotam uma elipse como figura de linguagem (palavra deliberadamente omitida pelo autor original que pode ser inferida por contexto) - o que não é o seu caso.

Comment: não será "" que deve utilizar ?

Answer (score 2):

As omissões em citações – permitidas quando não alteram o sentido da frase ou do texto – são indicadas pelo uso de reticências entre parênteses ou entre colchetes. Geralmente elas são utilizadas no interior de um trecho, no meio de uma oração ou entre uma frase e outra; ou entre um parágrafo e outro quando se suprime um parágrafo inteiro. Depois de definir um critério – parênteses ou colchetes –, siga-o até o fim do texto.

Exemplos:

```
As coleções são concebidas na sede do grupo, no Oregon [...], onde está concentrada sua capacidade de design.

O incentivo à criação do mercado mundial é onipresente em configurações de produção eficientes (...), redes de circulação (...) e de consumo (...).
```

Já o uso de reticências soltas (sem uso de colchetes ou parênteses) não encontra utilização nesse contexto, sendo restrito ao uso literário propriamente dito, geralmente no sentido de um ato executado de forma contínua:

```
Mascarenhas esperou por Natália mais um dia, mais um mês, mais um ano... até que cansou de esperar e foi atrás dela.
```

Entendemos, portanto, ser legítima a correção do trabalho, não cabendo recurso.

Comment: É isso, exatamente.